# Installing Program and Windows Directory Architecture

Tags: windows, installation, installshield

I am writing an installer for our application. It needs to place some dll's in the Win32 folder. On XP and later, the Win32 folder is usually located at C:\WINDOWS\system32. On Windows 2000, it seems that the folder is located at C:\WINNT\System32.

I have written my installer using InstallShieldLE. The [WindowsFolder] usually expands to C:\WINDOWS and then the System32 below that completes the path to C:\WINDOWS\system32. However, it does not expand to C:\WINNT\System32 on Windows 2000. Any ideas on how I can get this to work.

The images below show the current directory structure I am using, and the bottom picture shows all the possible selections.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the [SystemFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372055%28VS.85%29.aspx) Property.  However you should also be aware that it's generally bad form to deploy files to this directory these days.  Certainly not a best practice.  Also beaware of x86 vs x64 as described in the link.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Dont know if you can answer this or not. According to your link, on 64 bit versions, SystemFolder will map to C:\Windows\SysWow64. My application is written in Java, but it calls dll's that are located in the System32 folder. Will the calls to the System32 folder be forwarded to the SysWow64 folder?

Comment: I've never programmed in Java so I'm not sure how bitness issues effect it.